# how to import large file in a local cartodb running in a docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, large-files, cartodb

I'm using https://hub.docker.com/r/sverhoeven/cartodb/ docker image.
I've configured nginx as requested.

I have an up and running local cartodb, made some cool visualization.
I can upload 80MB files as many time as I want to.

However, when I try to upload a 240MB file, it doesn't even try. I immediately have a little pop up in the bottom left corner saying "Ouch! Error connecting my_csv.csv", and when I click to have more information, I have this more : "Unfortunately there was a connection error".

I don't know which log I should look at. Maybe it's cartodb that is failing, maybe it's a limit that my container has that I don't know about, maybe it comes from somewhere else.. I'm lost!

Comment: login to the container (`docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash`) and try read the log files for cartodb, postgres or nginx. One of them may have enabled a size limit.

Comment: I already did, but today I looked on local nginx logs, and found that : 2016/03/15 09:31:12 [error] 8500#0: *5184 client intended to send too large body: 137276047 bytes, client: 127.0.0.1, server: cartodb.localhost, request: "POST /user/dev/api/v1/imports HTTP/1.1", host: "cartodb.localhost", referrer: "http://cartodb.localhost/user/dev/dashboard/datasets"

Comment: I'll edit the local nginx conf

Comment: I modified the configuration file found in the github repository of that image to set the max body size to 3GB. It worked.

Comment: Should I delete this question as it is not very usefull ?

Answer (score 0):

in the description of the [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sverhoeven/cartodb/), it's stated that

> You need to add config/cartodb.nginx.proxy.conf to /etc/nginx/conf.d/.

this file can be found [here](https://github.com/sverhoeven/docker-cartodb/blob/master/config/cartodb.nginx.proxy.conf) and the following line has to be modified  to whatever size is needed: `client_max_body_size 100M;`

Also it is required to change the user permission in order to allow him to create tables with many rows.
Since it's a local cartodb, it is possible by connecting to the container(`docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash`), going to `/cartodb` and using the following command :

```
bundle exec rake cartodb:set_custom_limits_for_user[<user_name>,<import_file_size>,<table_row_count>,<concurrent_imports>]
```